# Maven: Find unmanaged dependencies

Tags: java, maven

Maven dependencies can be "managed" (the version is defined by a dependencyManagement entry) or "unmanaged" (the version is determined by Maven dependency mediation).

I would like to find all unmanaged dependencies in my build and warn about them. How could that be achieved?

Comment: would http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireUpperBoundDeps.html or http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html help in your overall objective ?

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-dependency-plugin` has several analysis goals that might help. From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) (plugin version 3.0.0):

- dependency:analyze analyzes the dependencies of this project and determines which are: used and declared; used and undeclared; unused and declared.
- dependency:analyze-dep-mgt analyzes your projects dependencies and lists mismatches between resolved dependencies and those listed in your dependencyManagement section.
- dependency:analyze-only is the same as analyze, but is meant to be bound in a pom. It does not fork the build and execute test-compile.
- dependency:analyze-report analyzes the dependencies of this project and produces a report that summarises which are: used and declared; used and undeclared; unused and declared.
- dependency:analyze-duplicate analyzes the  and  tags in the pom.xml and determines the duplicate declared dependencies.

Given your description of the use case, I'd experiment with `dependency:analyze-dep-mgt` first.